# How to type this thing

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

[image]

I was trying to ask a question on physics stackexchange but i don't know how to type this thing

I could have asked this same thing on physics stackexchange but i don't have enough reputation to post a pic there.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: This is more a question for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

The Latex code would be "\int_S\int \vec{A}\cdot\vec{n}dS= \int_S\int A cos(\theta)dS= \int_S\int \left(A_xdS_x+ A_ydS_y+ A_zdS_z\right)".  Depending on the board, you will need to wrap that in dollar signs "[ tex ][ /tex ]" or "[ math ][ /math ]" (without the spaces- I put those in so that would not be interpreted as a math formula.)  On this board, use dollar signs:
$\int_S\int \vec{A}\cdot\vec{n}dS= \int_S\int A cos(\theta)dS= \int_S\int \left(A_xdS_x+ A_ydS_y+ A_zdS_z\right)$